# navigation stack robot in-place rotations

Tags: ros, navigation, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I know this might be an old topic that the robot using navigation stack keeps turning on spot and since I've not been able to searched for a suitable solution for this, I raised the question here with hope that I could get some help.

I am using Fuete navigation stack on our tracked robot of rectangular shape with differential drive. There are two cases when I found the robot was performing a weird in-place rotating:

(1) when the robot is about to enter a narrow corridor, it is very likely that the robot would rotate several rounds before going into the corridor. The rotating direction will always be clock-wise. There were cases when the robot kept turning and seemed it would never want to proceed.

(2) also when the robot was going to a narrow space, by right it only needed to turn left (anti-clockwise) for maybe just a small angle and then it could go into the place, however, in fact it insisted on turning right (clockwise) and after this big round turning then went into the place.

Some one once suggested that this might be because of the recovery behaviours. But even we disabled the recovery behaviours, the problem remained. We believe it must be the base local planner.

Has anyone ever experienced the same problem and can give some advise one this? Thanks very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173338/navigation-stack-robot-in-place-rotations/) by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-13**:
Which local planner are you using?

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-06-14**:
Hi David, I am using the default TrajectoryPlannerROS. So we wanted give the DWAPlannerROS a try to see if it could solve the problem but DWAPlannerROS in our fuerte does not work. I placed an issue in git and was suggested to try the new version of local planner after Fuerte. May be Hydro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I remember seeing an issue or a commit indicating that this is fixed in the Hydro version of navigation, but I can't seem to find reference to it. Perhaps you can give the Hydro version of navigation a try and see if it fixes your bug?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-06-11**:
Hi ahendrix thanks. I did not find the reference either. We are planning to upgrade the ros from fuerte to hydro later but currently we are still working on tuning fuerte. I will try another local planer dwa_local_planner first. Thanks.